# Encontrar el dato que mejor satisface una condición de una base de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, pandas

Tengo una matriz **‘ingreso’** donde coloco en **‘ingreso[i][3]’** un código cualquiera que pertenece a una base de datos llamada **‘data’**.
Base de datos: [BASE_DE_DATOS](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AieO48E0rWr2lQwW0CaD1bJYIwoW)

```
import pandas as pd 
ingreso = [[1, 'Col', 'D', '21X62'],
           [2, 'Col', 'D', '12X62'],
           [3, 'Col', 'D', '21X68'],
           [4, 'Col', 'D', '21X62'],
           [5, 'Row', 'D', '12X45'],
           [6, 'Row', 'D', '12X45']]

ExcelPrincipal = pd.ExcelFile('ejemplo.xlsx')
base = []
for i in range(len(ingreso)): 
    if ingreso[i][2] == 'D':
        data = ExcelPrincipal.parse('D') 

    for j in range(len(data)):
        if ingreso[i][3] == data.values[j][0]:
            base.append([data.values[j][1], data.values[j][2]])     

print('Elemento',5*' ','Relación')
R_list = []
for i in range(len(ingreso)):
    if ingreso[i][1] == 'Col':
        R = round(base[i][1]/base[i][0],3) 
        R_list.append(R)

        print(f"{i+1:02} {R:>18}")
print('')
print('\n'.join(',   '.join(map(str,sl)) for sl in ingreso))

#while R_list[i] < 0.5:
#    for j in range(len(R_list)):
#        if ingreso[i][1] == 'Col':
#            R = round(base[i][1]/base[i][0],3) 
#            R_list.append(R)
```

Lo que intento hacer en éste código es que me devuelva una matriz **‘ingreso’** pero actualizada en donde los datos de la fila **‘ingreso[i][3]’** den como resultado una relación *mayor a 0.5.*

A manera de ilustración, mi matriz de **‘ingreso’** actual tiene lo siguiente:

```
[[1, 'Col', 'D', '21X62'],
 [2, 'Col', 'D', '12X62'],
 [3, 'Col', 'D', '21X68'],
 [4, 'Col', 'D', '21X62'],
 [5, 'Row', 'D', '12X45'],
 [6, 'Row', 'D', '12X45']]

Que dan como resultado las siguientes relaciones: 

Elemento       Relación
01              0.209
02              0.211
03              0.209
04              0.381
```

Lo que busco es hallar los primeros códigos de la base de datos tales que me de en cada elemento una relación *mayor a 0.5 (mayor a 0.5 y la más cercana a 0.5)*, por ejemplo:

```
[[1, 'Col', 'D', '12X336'],
 [2, 'Col', 'D', '12X336'],
 [3, 'Col', 'D', '12X336'],
 [4, 'Col', 'D', '12X336'],
 [5, 'Row', 'D', '12X336'],
 [6, 'Row', 'D', '12X336']]

Elemento       Relación
01              0.543
02              0.543
03              0.543
04              0.543
```

Creo se puede hacer con un bucle while hasta que encuentre pero podría existir alguna forma más conveniente, saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien, la base de datos `ejemplo.xlsx` en la `hoja D` hay tres columnas, la primera sin nombre contiene los `códigos` y las otras dos `a` y `b`.

Hay un estadístico `R` que se obtiene dividiendo `b / a`

Si sólo se quiere saber cuales `R > 0.5` y mantener los indices que le corresponde de excel , asumiendo como se muestra en la pregunta que pueden haber códigos repetidos, una posible implementación sería la siguiente:

```
data = ExcelPrincipal.parse(sheetname='D')
data.columns = ["codigo", "a", "b"]
data["R"] = data["b"] / data["a"]
data = data[data["R"] > 0.5]
data = data.reset_index()
data["index"] += 2 # igual a excel (los nombres de la columna ocupan la posicion 1)
```

Los datos quedaría así

```
print(data,"\n")
#     index  codigo         a         b         R
# 0       2    4X13  0.043754  0.025673  0.586752
# 1       3    5X16  0.054197  0.032340  0.596701
# 2       4    5X19  0.055237  0.032769  0.593234
# 3       9    6X15  0.065096  0.037079  0.569609
# 4      10    6X20  0.067435  0.038379  0.569115
# ..    ...     ...       ...       ...       ...
# 56    103  14X500  0.189946  0.112523  0.592394
# 57    104  14X550  0.193561  0.114080  0.589372
# 58    105  14X605  0.197978  0.115518  0.583493
# 59    106  14X665  0.202337  0.117729  0.581847
# 60    107  14X730  0.207476  0.119225  0.574643

# [61 rows x 5 columns] 

# Estadisticas de la columna R (promedio minimo maximos, cuartiles)
print(data["R"].describe())
# count    61.000000
# mean      0.586039
# std       0.021875
# min       0.542697
# 25%       0.571261
# 50%       0.583737
# 75%       0.602298
# max       0.630403
# Name: R, dtype: float64

# si necesitas un ranking de los R,
print(data.sort_values(by="R", ascending=False))
#     index  codigo         a         b         R
# 44     91  14X176  0.163139  0.102843  0.630403
# 42     89  14X145  0.161127  0.101517  0.630043
# 43     90  14X159  0.162284  0.102206  0.629800
# 46     93  14X211  0.166143  0.103667  0.623958
# 45     92  14X193  0.165328  0.103071  0.623438
# ..    ...     ...       ...       ...       ...
# 32     67  12X230  0.152269  0.084218  0.553089
# 33     68  12X252  0.153811  0.085018  0.552742
# 34     69  12X279  0.157143  0.085752  0.545698
# 35     70  12X305  0.159536  0.086806  0.544115
# 36     71  12X336  0.162664  0.088277  0.542697

# [61 rows x 5 columns]
```

Si por a o b motivos quisieras que el indice de `data` no sea `44, 42, 43, 46, 45...`

```
data = data.sort_values(by="R", ascending=False)
data = data.reset_index(drop=True) # esta vez no hay interes en conservar los indices que se van a resetar
print(data)
#   index  codigo         a         b         R
# 0      91  14X176  0.163139  0.102843  0.630403
# 1      89  14X145  0.161127  0.101517  0.630043
# 2      90  14X159  0.162284  0.102206  0.629800
# 3      93  14X211  0.166143  0.103667  0.623958
# 4      92  14X193  0.165328  0.103071  0.623438
# ..    ...     ...       ...       ...       ...
# 56     67  12X230  0.152269  0.084218  0.553089
# 57     68  12X252  0.153811  0.085018  0.552742
# 58     69  12X279  0.157143  0.085752  0.545698
# 59     70  12X305  0.159536  0.086806  0.544115
# 60     71  12X336  0.162664  0.088277  0.542697

# [61 rows x 5 columns]
```

La columna `index` corresponde a los indices de excel para poder verificar

Comment: Muchas gracias por su excelente respuesta y muy completa, justamente algo así necesitaba @Hubert Ronald.